# how to use regex in javascript to capture everything between two segments

Tags: regex

take this url

```
http://service.com/room/dothings?adsf=asdf&dafadsf=dfasdf
http://service.com/room/saythings?adsf=asdf&dafadsf=dfasdf
```

say if i want to capture `dothings`, `saythings`,
I now the following regex

```
/room\/(.+)\?/.exec(url)
```

and in the result i get this.

```
["room/dothings?", "dothings"]
```

what should i write to obtain the string above with only one item in an array.

Comment: You can't. The first element in the result is always the full match. All other elements are the group matches `(stuf)`. You could chain it though: `/x/.exec(y)[1]` or `y.match(/x/)[1]`

Comment: thanks. i was looking for someone to verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but parsing a URL with regex is not easy, and in some cases not even safe. I would do the parsing without regex.

In browser:

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = 'http://example.com/room/dothings?adsf=asdf&dafadsf=dfasdf';
```

In node.js:

```
var url = require('url');
var parser = url.parse('http://example.com/room/dothings?adsf=asdf&dafadsf=dfasdf');
```

And then in both cases:

```
console.log(parser.pathname.split('/')[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's actually easy. You were almost there.

With all the obligatory disclaimers about parsing html in regex...

```
<script>
var subject = 'http://service.com/room/dothings?adsf=asdf&dafadsf=dfasdf';
var regex = /room\/(.+)\?/g;
var group1Caps = [];
var match = regex.exec(subject);
while (match != null) {
    if( match[1] != null ) group1Caps.push(match[1]);
    match = regex.exec(subject);
}
if(group1Caps.length > 0) document.write(group1Caps[0],"<br>");
</script>
```

**Output:** dothings

If you add strings in subject you can `for (key in group1Caps)` and it will spit out all the matches.

[Online demo](http://js.do/code/37889)

Comment: thanks, what I looking for was a way to use regex to extract the target directly.

Comment: @user2167582 So that's what you want, or am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: what you wrote returns a single match, but what i was looking for was a pattern that returns only the capture group and not the entire expression, so in many frameworks such as angular, there are filters that uses ng-pattern for matching regex, if i use capture groups, it would return my desired result on second paramemter which is not useful and i sometimes need to rewrite, so a regex or a way to use regex in javascript such that matching expression isn't captured by default is what I was looking for. but if not i can rewrite over default patterns.